# How to make users log on to my site using their facebook account?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am using SDK php to make users login to my website using their Facebook account. I am following the SDK example. When I am trying to get the logged in user id it returns 0:

```
$id = $facebook->getUser();
```

could you please tell me what is the problem, and how to make the example with php SDK work

this is the code of the example:

```
<?php
$config = FacebookConfig::getConfig();
$facebook = new Facebook( $config );
$user = $facebook->getUser();
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[ CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ] = false;

if ( $user ) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api( '/me' );
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    }
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
        error_log( $e );
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    try {

        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
             "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
            "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:8888/www/index.php" 
        ) );
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api( '/me' );
        $userProf = $facebook->api( "/$user" );
        echo $user;
        echo $user_profile;
    }
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
        $user = null;
        echo "expetion in login";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: actually you should tell us what is the problem? and probably that `redirect_uri` wont work here because you are running it on a local server.

Comment: the problem is even when i log in the function getUser() returns 0, do not worry about redirecting it works well

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect the user to `$loginUrl`! Try this:

```
<?php
$config = FacebookConfig::getConfig();
$facebook = new Facebook( $config );
$user = $facebook->getUser();
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[ CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ] = false;

if ( $user ) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api( '/me' );
        var_dump($user_profile);
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    }
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
        error_log( $e );
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    try {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
             "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
            "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/facebook/index.php" 
        ) );
        header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
    }
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
        $user = null;
        echo "exception in login";
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not have such directory, please clarify your suggestion

Comment: change it to the url you want the user to get redirected to after facebook login.